# Prove that there exists an injection if $\# X \leq \# Y$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Proof that there exists an injection for $f: X \rightarrow Y$ if $\# X \leq \# Y$ and $X$ and $Y$ are finite sets.

I can not think of a way to proof this. Which method can I use to proof this?

Comment: What is your definition of $#X\le #Y$? The one I know is exactly the property of the existence of an injective function form $X$ to $Y$

Comment: $\# X \leq \# Y$ means that the amount of elements in $X$ is less or equal than the amount of elements in $Y$. So $X$ and $Y$ are $2$ finite sets.

Comment: So you are dealing with finite sets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $X = \{ x_1, \ldots, x_n \}$ and $Y = \{ y_1, \ldots, y_n, y_{n+1}, \ldots y_{n+k}\}$, where all $x$'s and all $y$'s are distinct.

Can you think of an injection $f\colon X\to Y$ now?

Comment: You can say that there exists an injection as every $x_{i}$ can have a different corresponding $y_{i}$ because $Y$ has more elements, right?

Comment: @NimaKimi and now just write your injection explicitly.